# ES7 timeout for async/await fetch

Tags: javascript, timeout, async-await, fetch-api, ecmascript-next

I want to set **timeout** in my `fetch` method, and I follow [this github issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175).

from [@mislav](https://github.com/mislav) answer, we could custom **timeout** method like below.

```
// Rough implementation. Untested.
function timeout(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      reject(new Error("timeout"))
    }, ms)
    promise.then(resolve, reject)
  })
}

timeout(1000, fetch('/hello')).then(function(response) {
  // process response
}).catch(function(error) {
  // might be a timeout error
})
```

and improved by [@nodkz](https://github.com/nodkz)

```
function timeoutPromise(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error("promise timeout"))
    }, ms);
    promise.then(
      (res) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        resolve(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  })
}
```

but I want to call that method in ES7 async/await syntax, I try below way but failed.

```
async request() {
  try { 
    let res = await timeout(1000, fetch('/hello'));
  } catch(error) {
    // might be a timeout error
  }
}
```

and how could I use it in ES7 async/await syntax?

thanks for your time.

---

### update

thanks for [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) reply, and I display my code in http request step.

#### ES7 fetch

```
'use strict';

import { configApi, } from 'tyrantdb-config';
import { timeoutPromise, } from 'xd-utils-kit';

const keyResponse = configApi.keyResponse;
const KEY_DATA = keyResponse.data;


module.exports = {
  async fetchLogin(url, params, dataRely) {
    let {
      self, processor, route,
      storage, isLocalStoraged,
      email, password, _warning, } = dataRely;

    self.setState({ isWait: true, });

    try {
      let res = await timeoutPromise(10, fetch(url, params));
      if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {

        let resJson = await res.json();
        let resData = resJson[KEY_DATA];

        let cache = {
          ...resData,
          password,
        };
        if (isLocalStoraged !== true) {
          processor(cache, storage);
        }
        global.g_user = cache;
        self.setState({ isWait: false, });

        // clean user info which already bind to self[this]
        self.email = self.password = null;
        self.isLocalStoraged = false;
        route();

      } else {
        console.log(`[login] response code: ${res.status}`);
        self.setState({ isWait: false, });
        _warning();
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },

  saveLoginState: (cache, storage) => {
    storage.save({
      key: 'loginState',
      rawData: cache,
    });
  },

  openURL: (url, Linking) => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        console.log(`can\'t handle url: ${url}`);
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(url);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(`error occurred: ${err}`);
    })
  },
};
```

---

#### ES6 fetch

```
'use strict';

import { configApi, } from 'tyrantdb-config';
import { timeoutPromise, } from 'xd-utils-kit';

const keyResponse = configApi.keyResponse;
const KEY_DATA = keyResponse.data;


module.exports = {
  fetchLogin(url, params, dataRely) {
    let {
      self, processor, route,
      storage, isLocalStoraged,
      email, password, _warning, } = dataRely;

    self.setState({ isWait: true, });

    timeoutPromise(1000, fetch(url, params))
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          console.log(`[login] response code: ${res.status}`);
          self.setState({ isWait: false, });
          _warning();
        }
      })
      .then((resJson) => {
        let resData = resJson[KEY_DATA];

        let cache = {
          ...resData,
          password,
        };
        if (isLocalStoraged !== true) {
          processor(cache, storage);
        }
        global.g_user = cache;
        self.setState({ isWait: false, });

        // clean user info which already bind to self[this]
        self.email = self.password = null;
        self.isLocalStoraged = false;
        route();
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .done();
  },

  saveLoginState: (cache, storage) => {
    storage.save({
      key: 'loginState',
      rawData: cache,
    });
  },

  openURL: (url, Linking) => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        console.log(`can\'t handle url: ${url}`);
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(url);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(`error occurred: ${err}`);
    })
  },
};
```

above ES6 fetch will catch output below, I think [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) is right, It's my code fault, not `timeoutPromise` error.

```
2016-06-08 22:50:59.789 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] [login] response code: 400
2016-06-08 22:50:59.808 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'KEY_DATA')]
  line: 103795,
  column: 29,
  sourceURL: 'http://172.26.129.189:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true' }
2016-06-08 22:50:59.810 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. This is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.
2016-06-08 22:50:59.810 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ', 'One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. This is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.'
```

Comment: Your `request` function seems to be working. What's wrong with it? Why do you think you failed?

Comment: I test ES6 fetch and set timeout 10ms, it catch my error. and I try my above syntax in ES7 async/await fetch, the same 10ms timeout param, but I get `possible unhandled promise rejection` error in react native console.

Comment: What's the rejection reason?

Comment: I don't really understand the output, when I try timeout in ES6 fetch, my catch will be console without any warning. __but now the output have warning__ >>>  `2016-06-08 22:07:11.606 [warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. This is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.`

Comment: Please show us the whole code. Apparently you're using `Object.assign` somewhere, and that throws an exception which for some reason is not caught in the promise chain handler but in the `catch` statement of the async function. The `timeout` function is not to blame here.

Comment: @Bergi  thanks for your patience, I'll update my question as soon as possible :)

Comment: I'd blame the `.setState` method as that's the only one used outside of the `try`. Also, how does the working `then` code look like?

Comment: @Bergi  Are you mean in ES6 fetch syntax?  I'll append it :)

Comment: @Bergi  I think you are right, thanks again. but how could I fix my code :(

Comment: The main difference is that the ES6 `fetchLogin` function doesn't return a promise. If there is any error before starting the chain, it'll just throw an exception; while your ES8 `async fetchLogin` returns a rejected promise. You probably will want to install an error handler at the point where you call the function.